# pandas series converts to method when set as column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe with columns col1 (object), col2 (float64).

```
type(df.col1)
type(df.col2)
```

both return

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

```
cumsum=df.col2.cumsum()
type(cumsum)
```

also returns

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

however

```
df['col3']=cumsum
type(df.col3)
```

returns

```
method
```

why is this? how can i add a series as a column of the dataframe and have it remain a series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why do not named the column with pandas original method

```
Cumsum = df.col2.cumsum()

df['col3']=Cumsum
type(df.col3)
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. why does naming the series 'cumsum' cause issues if i never called it df.cumsum?